# union and join on the same table

Tags: sql, join, amazon-rds, union

I have a table that looks like this:
TableA

```
 id| origin1 | origin2 | col4 ....
 1 | a       | a       | 434
 2 | c       | b       | 439
 3 | d       | d       | 8734
```

I want to get all the unique values between col b and col c, I used union for this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT origin1 as url, 'home' as source
  FROM TableA 
  UNION 
  SELECT origin2 as url, 'home2'
  FROM TableA
) AS data
```

I need to get the id per each row, in order to join the results to several tables including table a -

```
select id_1 as id, url, col 4,....
FROM (
  SELECT origin1 as url, 'home' as source, id as id_1
  FROM TableA
  UNION
  SELECT origin2 as url, 'home2', id
  FROM TableA 
) AS data
left join TableA on id_1 = TableA.id
```

expected results:

```
 id| url | col4 ....
 1 | a   | 434
 2 | c   | 439
 2 | b   | 439
 3 | d   | 8734
```

Actual results -
too many rows are added by the id.

is it possible to add the id for each row without duplication?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `'home' as source` and `'home2'` in your UNION, you have different `source` for each column, thus, you will never get an 'unique' result.
change it to,

```
select id_1 as id, url, col 4,....
FROM (
  SELECT origin1 as url, 'home' as source, id as id_1
  FROM TableA
  UNION
  SELECT origin2 as url, 'home', id
  FROM TableA 
) AS data
left join TableA on id_1 = TableA.id
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need some indication to know if the url value comes from the first part of the union or the second.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `NOT EXISTS` with your union query as the following:

```
SELECT id, url, source, col4
FROM
(
  SELECT id, origin1 AS url,'home' as source, col4 
  FROM TableA
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, origin2,'home2', col4 
  FROM TableA T
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TableA D WHERE D.id=T.id AND D.origin2=T.origin1)
) T
ORDER BY id, url
```